# Do not count \part{} page in latex

Tags: latex

i do'nt want to count the page number when i use \part{}, for example

```
...........
.         .
.         .
.         .
.    4    .
...........
...........
.         .
. Part I  .
.         .
.         .
...........

...........
.         .
.         .
.         .
.   5     .
...........
```

How can i get it?

Comment: Just to ask: why you should do that? I can't see any obvious reason to not count empty pages... If you just wont the page number to be displayed, use the empty pagestyle.

Comment: Actually skipping page numbers doesn't, on the face of it, seem a very sensible thing to do. You'll probably confuse your other readers, and you may have problems with odd/even page related things like starting a chapter on a recto page...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I'll take it into account

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will decrease the page number by one:

```
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
```

This will suppress the page number on the current page: (which you can leave out if the page number currently doesn't show up)

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

So, you can put together your own macro (I'm calling it `\mypart` but name it what you like) to do all three things at once:

```
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{\part{#1}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\thispagestyle{empty}}
```